# From Fundamental Polygon to Parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

For example, how did anyone go from the fundamental polygon of real projective space, or the klein bottle, to a parametrization?

Comment: What do you mean by "a parametrization"?

Comment: a coordinate map, such as the "bottle shape" section here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle

Comment: If we take for example the Klein bottle to be the quotient of the unit square by identifying its edges appropriately, then $(s,t) \mapsto [(s,t)]$ is a parametrization of the Klein bottle whose domain is the unit square and where $[(s,t)]$ denotes the equivalence class of $(s,t)$ on the Klein bottle.  But I don't think this is what you wanted...

Comment: Are you asking how to use the formula for gluing the polygon to produce coordinate charts of a manifold structure?

Comment: @LeeMosher yes! If only I could have been that succinct...